# Policy file error while loading images form facebook

Tags: flash, facebook

I making a game leaderboard on facebook. I'm not using connect but working inside the canvas. When I try to load the images from facebook it gives me the following error.

```
SecurityError: Error #2122: Security sandbox violation: Loader.content: http://test cannot access http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/v22941/254/15/q652310588_2173.jpg A policy file is required, but the checkPolicyFile flag was not set when this media was loaded.
```

Here is my loader code

```
    public var preLoader:Loader;
    preLoader=new Loader();
        **update**
        Security.loadPolicyFile('http://api.facebook.com/crossdomain.xml');
        Security.allowDomain('http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net');
        Security.allowInsecureDomain('http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net');
                    **update-end**


        public function imageContainer(Imagewidth:Number,Imageheight:Number,url:String,path:String) {
        preLoader=new Loader();

        Security.loadPolicyFile("http://api.facebook.com/crossdomain.xml");
        var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
        context.checkPolicyFile = true;
        context.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;

        preLoader.load(new URLRequest(path),context);
```

Any Ideas? I am importing the right class though.

**UPDATE:**
I am loading the images from a different domain say , calling func http://fahim.com images are from http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/v22941/254/15/q652310588_2173.jpg something ( I have made sure the pictures are static do not require a facebook login or anything , they are just user public profile pictures)

Comment: If you are loading from facebook, then why are you loading policy file from felinefrenzy.com?

Comment: @Amarghosh, I'm sorry I did not update that there. In my original code I'm using facebook crossdomain. I just updated that. It still gives me the exact same error.

@sberry2A, Yes I needed to change the name and I was using different URL's now an dthe facebook mention and so forth. Though all the changes still give me the same error.

Comment: Are you certain about this line too `context.checkPolicyFile = true;`? Is that part of the original code itself? The policy file at the said location seems to be okay.

Comment: got it working, the facebook policy file for images is somewhere else and I turned everything else to "*"

Answer (score 9):

This is the url to the image policy file:

```
Security.loadPolicyFile('https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/crossdomain.xml');
```

With this line everything should work just fine.

Comment: You must be a lot of fun at parties.

Answer (score 3):

```
var loaderContext:LoaderContext;
loaderContext= new LoaderContext();
loaderContext.securityDomain=SecurityDomain.currentDomain;
loaderContext.checkPolicyFile = true;
```

..then pass loaderContext when calling load()

Answer (score 1):

got it working, the facebook policy file for images is somewhere else and I turned everything else to "*"

Thanks for the help everyone.

Security.loadPolicyFile('https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/crossdomain.xml');

Comment: what is the url of  Facebook policy file for images??

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to display any image, without getting its data a good workaround is not trying to use this data. In that case, you don't need the allow security and cross domain file stuff.  Use only a simple loading code:

```
backgroundLoader.unload();
backgroundLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT,backgroundImageLoaded, false, 0, true);

var lc : LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
lc.checkPolicyFile = false;
backgroundLoader.load(new URLRequest(imagePath_),lc);
```

where backgroundLoader is a class variable of type Loader. Then when it comes to using the image to add it to your canvas, do not request the data (do not use e.currentTarget.content), only display the image:

```
function backgroundImageLoaded(e:Event) : void {
   myMovieClip.addChild(backgroundLoader);
}
```

(Solution from http://www.onegiantmedia.com/as3--load-a-remote-image-from-any-url--domain-with-no-stupid-security-sandbox-errors)