# Policy file error while loading new profile pictures from Facebook

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, flash

As you might know, for loading images from Facebook in our application (in my case AS3) we have to load following policy file:

```
Security.loadPolicyFile('https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/crossdomain.xml');
```

otherwise we get following error:

```
SecurityError: Error #2122: Security sandbox violation: Loader.content: http://test cannot access http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/v22941/254/15/q652310588_2173.jpg A policy file is required, but the checkPolicyFile flag was not set when this media was loaded.
```

you can find related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112823/policy-file-error-while-loading-images-form-facebook).

I have a Facebook application that is running for long time without problem, but what I am facing today which is bizarre, is that the application gives the same security error message while loading **NEW PROFILE PICTURE**, and for the profile pictures that have been uploaded about 2-3 weeks ago or earlier, there is no problem.

My question is that did Facebook change its policy? Is it a problem form my side or something is wrong from Facebook? I have googled to see if the Facebook's policy or something else has been changed, but I did not found any clue.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/crossdomain.xml you will see that it returns an error (403 Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /36477/crossdomain/pics-crossdomain.xml on this server) so Flash never gets a valid crossdomain file.

This is an issue that Facebook needs to address.

I know of no way to have Flash ignore crossdomain errors.